# Bash script: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

I have the following file and I have chmod a+x on the file.
When I try to run it, I get a line 75: syntax error: unexpected end of file. What is the error with my script? What do I need to do to fix it?

```
#!/bin/sh
# log directory for ascp transfer
logdirectory=/tmp/log20079
# log for this script
baselog=$logdirectory/sent4files.log
#directory of where the files to be transferred are located
basedirectory=/tmp/test20079/

#remote host data
REMOTE_DIR=/Upload
REMOTE_HOST=xxx
REMOTE_USER=xxx
# extensions of file
FEATURE_EXT=feature
KEYART_EXT=keyart
TRAILER_EXT=trailer
METADATA_EXT=metadata

# files to be excluded, must match exclude_file_suffix
COMPLETE_EXT=complete
SENT_EXT=sent

# file to send on completion
FILE_ON_COMPLETE="$basedirectory"delivery.complete

if [ "$TYPE" == "File" ]; then
   if [ "$STARTSTOP" == "Stop" ]; then
     if [ "$STATE" == "success" ]; then
        filename=$(basename "$FILE")
        extension="${filename##*.}"

# check the extension here, and create files ending in .sent as a flag

        case "$extension" in

        "$FEATURE_EXT")
           cat > "$basedirectory$FEATURE_EXT.$SENT_EXT" << 'EOF'
           EOF
           echo "Feature sent" >> $baselog
            ;;
        "$KEYART_EXT")
           cat > "$basedirectory$KEYART_EXT.$SENT_EXT" << 'EOF'
           EOF
           echo "Keyart sent" >> $baselog
            ;;
        "$TRAILER_EXT")
           cat > "$basedirectory$TRAILER_EXT.$SENT_EXT" << 'EOF'
           EOF
           echo "Trailer sent" >> $baselog
            ;;
        "$METADATA_EXT")
           cat > "$basedirectory$METADATA_EXT.$SENT_EXT" << 'EOF'
           EOF
           echo "Metadata sent" >> $baselog
           ;;
        esac


# check that all four files exists
        if [ -e "$basedirectory$FEATURE_EXT.$SENT_EXT" ] && [ -e "$basedirectory$KEYART_EXT.$SENT_EXT" ] && [ -e "$basedirectory$TRAILER_EXT.$SENT_EXT" ] && [ -e "$basedirectory$METADATA_EXT.$SENT_EXT" ]; then
          echo "All files sent" >> $baselog
          echo>$FILE_ON_COMPLETE
#         $FILE_ON_COMPLETE "$REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST:$REMOTE_DIR"
          rm "$basedirectory$FEATURE_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
          rm "$basedirectory$KEYART_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
          rm "$basedirectory$TRAILER_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
          rm "$basedirectory$METADATA_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
          rm $FILE_ON_COMPLETE
        fi

     fi
   fi
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heredocs are tricky beasts to get right. If you use `'EOF'` that's *exactly* what the closing line needs to be, with no whitespace at the front like you have.

Alternatively, you can use the `<<-` variant which strips off all leading tab characters from the lines in the heredoc *and* the closing line as per the following transcript (where `<tab>` is the <kbd>TAB</kbd> character):

```
pax> cat <<-'eof'
...> 1
...< 2
...> <tab>eof
...> 4
...> eof

1
2
<tab>eof
4

pax> cat <<-'eof'
...> 1
...> 2
...> <tab>eof

1
2
```

Using the `<<-` variant allows for neater files, thoug it's no good if you want to preserve leading tabs of course. From the `bash` manpage:

> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

Of course, if you're just wanting to use those files as flag files, there's a better way than `cat` with a heredoc. Just use:

```
touch "$basedirectory$FEATURE_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist and update the modification time if it does, just like the `cat` but without messing about with heredocs. It won't *empty* the file but, if you need that for some reason:

```
rm -f "$basedirectory$FEATURE_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
touch "$basedirectory$FEATURE_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
```

will do the trick.

However, since the heredoc *does* actually output a single empty line (one `\n` character), you can opt for:

```
echo >"$basedirectory$FEATURE_EXT.$SENT_EXT"
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, paxdiablo! You read my mind! I was actually using cat to create a flag! I'm still having syntax issues even after removing cat, and subtituting with touch.

Comment: @chuacw, then ask another question. There's no quota system here :-)

Comment: LOL, I succeeded. Make a silly mistake. Thanks paxdiablo!

Comment: Additionally, use a bash here-string instead of a here-doc: `cat > file <<< ""`

Answer (score 5):

The end of your heredocs `EOF` can not have any whitespace in front of them. Remove those spaces.