# syntax error: unexpected end of file when sourcing a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh

I am getting ***unexpected end of file*** error when use using source command to source a file.

***I know how to use if..else loop in bash***, this is a legacy script. The same script works properly if I run it in tcsh shell. Is there any way to make the script work both in bash & tcsh ?

below is my script,

```
bash>
bash> source del
-bash: del: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash>
bash> cat del
if ( `uname` == Linux ) then
    echo "One"
else
    echo "Two"
endif
bash>
```

I have already tried all the below solutions but none of them worked..

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100638/syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-when-running-source)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929705/bashrc-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057087/bash-script-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)

[Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886268/shell-script-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)

[Link 5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259994/error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-bash-profile)

[Link 6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317155/unexpected-end-of-file-in-shell-script)

[Link 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154427/unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching-bash-script)

Any reference on this would also be of great help !

Comment: bash and tcsh provide different languages. You can't have bash run the code of a tcsh script. If you want to source a file in bash, that file must be written in the language tha bash understands.

Comment: in bash it is `if <cond>; then... else... fi`

Comment: @PTRK yes i know the if..else in bash but this is a legacy script and this is not working only in bash..is there any way to make it work in both bash & tcsh ?

Comment: This script do not work at `bash` shell, the `if` estructure end with `fi`, see this [link](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php)

Comment: If you need use this in `bash` and `tcsh`, you can add a condition for shell type, something like: `if < echo $SHELL == /bin/bash >`

Comment: as @nos said, bash will only understand bash code. Since tcsh and bash are different, I wont think you can achieve your goal.

Comment: In general, you probably cannot write a full script that behaves the same in `bash` and `tcsh`. For this snippet, you *could* write ``test `uname` = Linux && echo One || echo Two``. Here, `&&` and `||` are the only two pieces of shell syntax used (`test` is an ordinary external command), and they are supported by both shells. (However, `... && ... || ...` will not always work as a replacement for an `if` statement.)

Answer (score 1):

[Please go through this link](https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash-scripting/bash-if-else-statement/)

In bash script the correct syntax for `if....else` is

```
if [ condition ]
then
        //block 1
else
       //block 2
fi
```

You can change your code to

```
if [ $(uname) == Linux ]
then
    echo "ONE"
else
    echo "TWO"
fi
```

[image: It works fine]

Comment: Duplicate of @Pritam answer. Also doesn't answer to the original author problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a `(t)csh` source. Please try `tcsh del` (or `csh del`). Of course you should have installed `csh` (or `tcsh`).

Answer (score -1):

Correct you script like below. Your `if` condition is not correctly closed.

```
system=$(uname)
if [[ $system == "Linux" ]]; then
   echo "One"
else
   echo "Two"
fi
```

Comment: Your `if` is not correct and would produce an error message. Substitute it by `if [[ \`uname\` == Linux ]]`. Also, since we know that the context is bash, it's besser to not use the obsolete backquotes, but write `if [[ $(uname) == Linux ]]`.

Comment: @user1934428, thanks for your advice. I have already corrected my answer